# Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string in main.loader.php on line 111

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

The code I'm doing maintenance is a school system, I'm having problems when it arrives in the part of starting the enrollment, it returns an object error, that is in line 111, in my code this is giving error in line 111 in

```
$qryMatricula = $conn->query($sqlMatricula);
echo $qryMatricula;
```

What could I be? How can I solve this?

main.loader.php

```
<?php      

                $sqlMatricula = "SELECT M.Situacao FROM {$pfx}Matricula M 
                                    INNER JOIN {$pfx}Curso C ON (C.CursoID = M.CursoID)
                    WHERE AlunoID = $alunoid AND C.PeriodoLetID = $periodoid";



                $qryMatricula = $conn->query($sqlMatricula);

                echo $qryMatricula;
                $situacaoMatricula = 0;
                if ($m = $qryMatricula->fetchObject()) 
                    $situacaoMatricula = $m->Situacao;
```

Comment: What error are you getting? What is it supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using [`PDO::query()`](https://www.php.net/manual/de/pdo.query.php) which returns an instance of a [`PDOStatement`](https://www.php.net/manual/de/class.pdostatement.php) object and could not be converted to a string with `echo`.

Try the following:

```
$sth = $conn->query($sqlMatricula);
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: so it returns an empty array, and the error on the bottom line where it is:
if ($ m = $ qryMatricula-> fetchObject ())

Comment: The error you recieve is that you try to echo an object, which could not be converted to a string. If you remove the echo then the error will disappear. When you get an emty result after the fetchAll from my example, then your db call gives you nothing back. Did you try the mysql call direct on the db to check for results? And BTW the fetchAll was just an example, just remove the echo from your code.